# Is it possible to integrate htmx in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Does anybody try to use htmx in magento context ?
As I know it's need to connect external js lib in order to use htmx, does any conflicts appears in magento when you will use this lib ?
Advantages and disadvantages ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sprinkle htmx to magento Luma theme, all you need is to include this external JS lib and you will instantly get the hx directives available working with your custom APIs that renders incremental document updates.

If you swap out the whole Luma stack (knockout, requirejs, ui compoments, local storage etc) with HTMX, then it will be a very challenging task (which I am thinking about) and probably requires a team, but the advantage will be obvious:
faster site rendering
faster development
much better developer experience